# How to use Matlab's bsxfun to solve cumulative sum

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, bsxfun

I have the following (slow) piece of code:

```
% A is n-by-m matrix
% B is n-by-m-by-d matrix
% C is n-by-m-by-d matrix
% R is 1-by-d vector

A=zeros(n,m);
for i=1:d
    A = A + sum(B(:,:,1:i),3).*(R(i)-C(:,:,i));
end
```

I would like to make it more efficient by using the magical bsxfun to lose the loop. Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way -

```
A = sum(cumsum(B,3).*bsxfun(@minus,permute(R,[1 3 2]),C),3)
```

With size parameters `n,m,d` as `200` each, the runtimes were

```
----------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.054771 seconds.
----------------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 2.514884 seconds.
```

More reasons to use [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`vectorization`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html)!!

---

### Benchmarking

Benchmarking Code -

```
n = 10;
m = 1000;
d = 3;
num_iter = 10000;

B = rand(n,m,d);
C = rand(n,m,d);
R = rand(1,d);

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp(['********************* d = ' num2str(d) ' ************************'])

disp('----------------------------------- With Proposed Approach')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    A1 = sum(cumsum(B,3).*bsxfun(@minus,permute(R,[1 3 2]),C),3);
end
toc

disp('----------------------------------- With Original Approach')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    
    A = zeros(n,m);
    for i=1:d
        A = A + sum(B(:,:,1:i),3).*(R(i)-C(:,:,i));
    end
end
toc
```

Runtimes at my end were -

```
********************* d = 3 ************************
----------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.856972 seconds.
----------------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 1.703564 seconds.



********************* d = 9 ************************
----------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 2.098253 seconds.
----------------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 9.518418 seconds.
```

Comment: Thank you but actually d is around d is 3~9 usually and for some reason the original approach is significantly faster. try n=10; m=1000; d=3; for example.

Comment: Very nice Divakar, I tried the same thing but couldn't see the `bsxfun` in their, I did `repmat(reshape(R,1,1,3),size(C,1),size(C,2),1)-C` instead which wasn't too much slower. Mat, I'm still seeing the original method take around 50% longer than Divakar's.

Comment: The variance between tests is very big. I did a test run for 1000 trials and indeed I get about 50% longer with the for loop. It's very good! don't get me wrong, I just wish it was as good as the 450% in Divakar answer...

Comment: @Mat Check out the benchmarking edits? The idea is to use a big number of trials so that the total runtime is around one sec mark. I think the preferred way to benchmark would be with [`timeit`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html). Also, the idea with vectorization is that you have a big number of loops, because otherwise as a limiting case, when you have the number of iteration as `1`, your loop is non-significant.

Comment: @Mat Haha I guess so, and lots of RAM, which is the most important thing when dealing with `bsxfun`, it likes to devour on RAM like a beast! Please keep that in mind! :)