# generate periodic function from given function

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization

let say that from given  function f(t), we want to construct new function  which is given from existed function by this way

[image]

where T is some constant let say T=3; of course  k can't be  from  -infinity to infinity  in reality because  we can't do infinity summation using computer,so  it is first my  afford

first let us define our function

```
function y=f(t);
y=-1/(t^2);
end
```

and second  program

```
k=-1000:1:999;
F=zeros(1,length(k));
T=3;
for t=1:length(k)
F(t)=sum(f(t+k*T));
end
```

but when i am running  second program ,i am getting

```
>> program
Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.

Error in f (line 2)
y=-1/(t^2);

Error in program (line 5)
F(t)=sum(f(t+k*T));
```

so i have two question related to this program :

1.first what  is error  why it shows me mistake

2. how can i do it in excel?  can i simplify it somehow? thanks in advance

EDITED :

i have changed my code  by this way

```
k=-1000:1:999;
F=zeros(1,length(k));
T=3;
for t=1:length(k)
    result=0;
    for l=1:length(k)
        result=result+f(t+k(l)*T);
    end
    F(t)=result;
end
```

is it ok?

Comment: The operators `+, -, *, /, ^, ...` are matrix operators. If you want to do elementwise operations you need to use the corresponding elementwise operators, `.+, .-, .*, ./, .^, ...`, where `+` and `-` is not necessary of course.

Comment: i have updated my code,please see it

Comment: Your function `y` needs to have element-wise powers being applied to the elements:  `y = -1/(t.^2);`.

Comment: @datodatuashvili The code before was better since it was vectorized. Just use the elementwise operators so that your function accepts vector input.

Comment: but how ?i have tried vectorization but no result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your problem in a vectorized way, you'll have to change the function `f` such that it can be called with vectors as input. This is, as @patrik suggested, achieved by using the element-wise operators `.* ./ .^` *(Afaik, no `.+ .-` exist)*. Unfortunately the comment of @rayryeng is not entirely correct, which may have lead to confusion. The correct way is to use the element-wise operators for both the division `./` *and* the square `.^`:

```
function y = f(t)
    y = -1 ./ (t.^2);
end
```

Your existing code (first version)

```
k = -1000:1:999;
F = zeros(1,length(k));
T = 3;
for t=1:length(k)
    F(t) = sum(f(t+k*T));
end
```

then works as expected (and is much faster then the version you posted in the edit).

You can even eliminate the for loop and use [`arrayfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) instead. For simple functions `f`, you can also use [function handles](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) instead of creating a separate file. This gives

```
f = @(t) -1 ./ (t.^2);
k = -1000:1:999;
t = 1:2000;
T = 3;
F = arrayfun(@(x)sum(f(x+k*T)), t);
```

and is even faster and a simple one-liner. `arrayfun` takes any function handle as first input. We create a function handle which takes an argument `x` and does the sum over all `k`: `@(x) sum(f(x+k*T)`. The second argument, the vector `t`, contains all values for which the function handle is evaluated.

As proposed by @Divakar in comments, you can also use the `bsxfun` function:

```
f = @(t) -1 ./ (t.^2);
k = -1000:1:999;
t = 1:2000;
T = 3;
F = sum(f(bsxfun(@plus,k*T,t.')),2);
```

where `bsxfun` creates a matrix containing all combinations between `t` and `k*T`, they are all evaluated using `f(...)` and last, the `sum` along the second dimension sums over all `k`'s.

---

**Benchmarking**

Lets compare these solutions:

1. Combination of `for` loop and `sum` (original question):

   > Elapsed time is 0.043969 seconds.
2. Go through all combinations in 2 `for` loops (edited question):

   > Elapsed time is 1.367181 seconds.
3. Vectorized approach with `arrayfun`:

   > Elapsed time is 0.063748 seconds.
4. Vectorized approach with `bsxfun` as proposed by @Divakar:

   > Elapsed time is 0.099399 seconds.

So (sadly) the first solution including a `for` loop beats both vectorized approaches. For larger `k` vectors (`-10000:1:9999`), this behavior can be reproduced. The conclusion seems to be that MATLAB has indeed learned how to optimize `for` loops.

Comment: Lose the loop with `F = sum(f(bsxfun(@plus,k*T,[1:length(k)].')),2)`?

Comment: @Divakar thanks, I added your solution to my answer and did a benchmarking. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Can you use few iterations on top of those, like the use of `num_iter` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29620906/3293881)? The idea would be to vary that number `num_iter` such that the total runtimes are around 1 sec mark, the more the better of course. This is to keep the variations with tic-toc at minimum. Warming up tic-toc at the start could also be beneficial.